# Does DisplayPort cables only one-way?

Tags: cable, adapter, displayport, mini-displayport, display-adapter

I saw this [DELOCK 82438 Mini DisplayPort - Displayport cable](http://www.delock.de/produkte/G_82438/merkmale.html) where the image shows one end is an input, while the other is an output. They also say in the description that this is a Mini DisplayPort male > DisplayPort male cable, indicating the direction.

[image: Mini DisplayPort male > DisplayPort male cable]

Does this really exist? A DisplayPort cable with one direction? What makes the data "flow" only to one way?

Comment: I can't think of any "output" devices or monitors etc that have a mini-dp in.  The mac monitors have a thunderbolt in but that's not the same thing.  I do have one of those types of mini-dp to dp cables connected from my mac to a AURIA 27" and it works well.

Comment: @Optichip It's been five years, so some there some monitors with it, now. For one, the Dell U2717D has both regular and mini DisplayPort inputs.

Comment: The Samsung U24E850R also has regular and mini DP inputs. It comes with a regular to mini DP cable and it works in both directions so if you are concerned then perhaps buy a Samsung cable from a monitor being sold separately.

Answer (score 2):

The only difference is the connector; the mini and regular connectors are electrically equivalent. According to Wikipedia,

> The mDP pin assignments are the same as the full-size DisplayPort connector.